# PHP/MySQL slow when querying 10000+ rows, but fast querying 9000

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a table with 14000 rows, and an application written in PHP/CodeIgniter querying this table with Active Record.

When I set a limit of 9000, it takes about 5 seconds to retrieve the rows, but if the limit is aorund 10000 or more, it takes more than 30-45 seconds.

I'm completely noob setting up Apache and MySQL and I suspect changing some parameters this 10000+ rows query will be executed faster.

What it could be?

Here is the table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `accesos` (
 `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `usuario` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 `base_datos` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
 `fecha` date NOT NULL,
 `hora` time NOT NULL,
 `ip` varchar(75) NOT NULL,
 `navegador` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
 `erroneo` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `audi_f_c` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `audi_f_a` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 `audi_u` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `usuario` (`usuario`),
 KEY `base_datos` (`base_datos`),
 KEY `audi_u` (`audi_u`),
 KEY `fecha` (`fecha`,`hora`),
 CONSTRAINT `accesos_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`usuario`) REFERENCES `usuarios` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
 CONSTRAINT `accesos_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`base_datos`) REFERENCES `bases_datos` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
 CONSTRAINT `accesos_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`audi_u`) REFERENCES `usuarios` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=14189 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: Have you run an `EXPLAIN` query? Do you have indexes ( I don't see any) on your table? 10k rows should be less than a second.

Comment: I have indexes in columns {usuario},{base_datos},{fecha,hora},{audi_u}

Comment: Could it be Apache or MySQL don't have enough space in memory to allocate all this amount of data?

Comment: Think about it: Why would you ever need to retrieve thousands of rows into memory? There are many other ways to do it. Normally you would never run into this problem.

Comment: I see keys, not [indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimization-indexes.html). Once you have a table indexed run `EXPLAIN` queries to make sure you're using the indexes.

Comment: You might be hitting a memory limit. Use "Show Processlist" to see if any temp tables are being generated once you go over the limit.

Comment: If you can show us the explain plan (edited into the question) that would be great too. Also, this chunk size is very high - what is your use case? You are obviously not paginating for record browsing, since no-one would want to read in chunks of 9000. If this is for an offline process, consider breaking the chunk size to, say, 1000, and then just repeat the query several times.

Comment: what is the query? can you EXPLAIN it ? ( http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html )

Comment: I've found what was happening. I was working with this library of CodeIgniter: https://github.com/jamierumbelow/codeigniter-base-model that has callback functions before and after get rows of the database server. When trying to retrieve more than 9000 rows these after get callbacks are very slowly, so I remove then and the server response takes less than a second.